# Constant height of chart regardless number of series displayed in legend

Tags: highcharts, height, legend

How to configure the chart options to get a constant height chart 
regardless the number of series displayed in the legend ?

Below 2 links to exported charts showing the problem.
Notice that the height of the chart has descreased.
Ideally, the legend would be displayed at the bottom of the
chart when user process to an export of the chart.

Let me know if I have missed something from the documentation.

Best regards
Patrick

Comment: Set maxHeight for legend: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.maxHeight

Comment: Humm. Not sure to have what I want with that option.
I would like the legend placed at the bottom of the chart with
a fixed height whatever the number of series displayed.
And this only when I do export (for online, the legend is placed
on the right of the chart and handles perfectly the different
numbers of series).

Hope that I am clearer.

Comment: Forget to add answer here: in general use `exporting.chartOptions`, where you can set options only for exported chart.